# Extract routers mac address using regex from multiple line of string output

Tags: python, json, api, mac-address

I want to extract mac-address from devices discovery in python. Each device discovery will return mac-address of the devices and extract the mac address of each devices. The mac-address of each devices will be unique and I just need to extract the mac-address part and remove others.

I send router command in python code as below

```
 show chassis mac-addresses | match "Private base"
```

The router command will return output like below in router terminal

```
 Private base address    00:1c:95:b9:e7:f0

{master}
```

There is few lines of string that need to be removed and only to extract mac address.

This is the code i used to send the command in python

```
output_mac = connection.send_command('show chassis mac-addresses | match 
"Private base"')

print("router_mac1: " + re.sub('\{|master|\:|0|\}|\\n','',output_mac))
```

The result output is as follows

```
router_mac:   Private base address    1db5d9e7f
```

From the output there is a lot of space, missing '0' and ':' .
I just want to get the mac-address, for example here just 00:1c:95:b9:e7:f0
May I know how can I extract correctly the mac address of each devices. Appreciate your help and kind support. Thank you

I expect the output of each devices will be as below

```
router_mac1:00:1c:95:b9:e7:f0
router_mac2:00:3b:25:c6:f3:d0
```

---

Based on the example, i tried

```
print("router_mac: " + re.findall(r'.([0-9a-fA-F]{2}[:]){5}([0-9a-fA-F] 
{2})',output_mac))
```

but i got error return

```
print("router_mac: " + re.findall(r'([0-9a-fA-F]{2}[:]){5}([0-9a-fA-F] 
{2})',output_mac))
TypeError: must be str, not list
```

---

Hi,

I tried use regex for mac address as follows;

```
re1='.*?' 
re2='((?:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]:){5}(?:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]))(?![:0-9A-F])' 
rg=re.compile(re1+re2,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
m = rg.search(output3)
if m:
  mac1 = m.group(1)
  print("router_mac1: " + mac1 + "\n")
```

it return the mac address but also create new empty line below  as follow

```
hostname: XC1-rtr-bkg
router_mac1: 00:1c:95:b9:e7:f0

model_type: T320
```

it should be

```
hostname: XC1-rtr-bkg
router_mac1: 00:1c:95:b9:e7:f0
model_type: XXX
```

How to remove the extra line above? thanks

**I remove \n**

Comment: I have gone through the answers from previous questions. I just don't know how to apply it to the code. I really appreciate if someone could help. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply regex for mac address onto the code, appreciate some help and thank you for your attention